# UIDocumentInteractionController download file failed when the PDF size is big

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I download and display PDF from my swift application using this code:

```
var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!
let pdfUrl = NSURL(string: "ENTER_URL_OF_PDF")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    downloadDoc(pdfUrl: pdfUrl!)
}

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    docController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
}

func downloadDoc(pdfUrl : NSURL) {
    let urlTest = self.pdfUrl!.absoluteString
    let pdfUrl = NSURL(string: urlTest!)
    if(pdfUrl != nil){
        let pdfRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: pdfUrl! as URL)
         NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(pdfRequest as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            if(httpResponse?.statusCode == 200 && error == nil){
               let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first as! NSURL

               if let fileName = self.pdfUrl!.lastPathComponent {
                  let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                  if let data = data {
                        do {
                            try data.write(to: destinationUrl!, options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: destinationUrl!)
                  }
               }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I try with a PDF containing grater than 3 pages, I got this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and my app crash. When I searched about the max size that can be downloaded I read in man SO posts that there is no limit! 
So why I got this problem?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error? Why does your code contain so many uses of forced unwrapping?

Comment: this one     `docController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)` in the IBAction so when I tap the button my app crash

Comment: That implies that `docController` is `nil`. Why are you trying to present a possibly `nil` controller without verifying that it isn't `nil`? Your code is littered with forced unwrapping bombs. You need to fix all of them.

Comment: You're right! But why I got a `nil` just when the size of the file is big?

Comment: You haven't told us enough to know. I assume you are calling `buttonAction` some time after `downloadDoc` has had a chance to run. Which of the many `if` statements in `downloadDoc` is failing? What debugging have you done?

Comment: I discover that when my view is loaded then I tap the button, the `docController` when I leave it for I moment then the download is completed so I can open the file.

Comment: I think that I have to display a loader until the pdf is downloaded. Thank you @maddy !